# Adam & Eve as parable- Kefira?

Tags: adam, heresy

Is believing that the Adam & Eve story was a parable and not to be read literally, considered Kefira (heresy)? Are there any Gedolim that sanction this position? I know there are other very similar questions regarding the story of Adam & Eve as parable, but the basis of my question regards the “appropriateness” or the “kosherness” of claiming a belief that the story is meant as parable.

I should qualify my question by letting you know that this small clip led to my wonder of whether such a statement (50 seconds long) can be called heretical or not: https://youtu.be/AXF0AIQrr8I

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66125/1739 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64380/1739

Comment: I think of it as a parable based on a true story. The only value the story has for us is as a parable. Anyone who insists the story be read literally with nothing to learn from it is completely missing the point, and that is probably kefira.

Comment: @simyou similarly, anyone who says it's a simple parable is definitely a heretic as well. The question is if it's a deep parable.

Comment: @DoubleAA *definitely* a heretic? Bit strong...

Answer (score 0):

Adding my grain of salt here:

ספורנו בראשית  ג א

> וְהַנָּחָשׁ. 'הוּא שָׂטָן הוּא יֵצֶר הָרָע', ... וְעַל זֶה הַדֶּרֶךְ
> קָרָא בָּזֶה הַמָּקום אֶת הַיֵּצֶר הָרָע הַמַּחְטִיא "נָחָשׁ",
> בִּהְיותו דּומֶה לְנָחָשׁ

Seforno Bereshit 3:a

And the serpent: It's is the Satan, it's is the *yetzer hara*...according to this line of thought the *yetzer hara*, the tempter, is called serpent, because it's like a serpent...