# Do Bereshit 1:27 and Bereshit 2:7 talk about 2 different creations for humans?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, creation, adam, eve-chava

Bereshit 1:27 states that mankind was created on the 6th day and that they (mankind) were created male and female, together. But later, in Bereshit 2:7, it states that Adam was created (at some undisclosed date) and that Chava was created at a later date. Bereshit 2:7 states that G-d breathed life into Adam's nostrils (G-d formed the Human from the soil’s humus, blowing into his nostrils the breath of life: the Human became a living being.) while Bereshit 1:27 doesn't mention G-d "breathing life" into man's nostrils. Does, Bereshit 2:7 merely give a more in depth description of the creation of mankind, or do Bereshit 2:7 and Bereshit 1:27 talk about 2 different creations, Bereshit 1:27 being the creation of all mankind and Bereshit 2:7 being the creation of the specific people Adam and Chava?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40218.

Comment: The answer to your specific question is found here, starting on the paragraph which  begins talking about the Nachash. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/133804/7303

Comment: See also [Rashi, Bereishis 2:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.2.8.1?lang=bi).